# Html img after label element

Tags: html, css, label

**Hi,**

I have the following HTML :

```
<div class="controlTitleContainer ">
    <label for="test">Titel</label>
    <div class="q">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

The CSS looks like this

```
.controlTitleContainer .label
{
    font-size:              0.94em;
    color:                  #778899;
    display:inline;
}

.controlTitleContainer .q
{
    background-image:       url("Images/Common/Icons/questionMark_15x14.png");
    height:                 14px;
    width:                  15px;
    float:left;
}
```

The problem is that the div will be placed to the left of the label instead of to the right? Why?

I have tried to switch the div to a span with no success. Also If I change the div to a img intead then it will work but there is some unvanted margins that I can´t remove with the div element.

**Pleas advice**

Edit1: The confusions in the question should now be fixed, sorry for that.

**MySolution :** I created two div elements (one for text and one for icon) and then set float to left on both.

Comment: Take out the `float:left` and you're good

Comment: There seems to be a bit of confusion in the question, but yes basically just take the float and that should do. PS: LP Meteora ftw!

Comment: Thanks but that did not help. The div will be position under the label?

Answer (score 2):

You're quite confused. You talk about `IMG` in question title, then you present `SPAN` in your code and afterwards talk about `DIV` in your text.

But I guess all three refer to `SPAN` in your code since you do set a background image to your `SPAN` element.

### Solution

Anyway. Your `span` is floated left according to your CSS. If you remove the following line in your style sheet, your `span` will appear to the right of your `label`:

```
float: left; /* <- remove this */
```

> > **Edit**: I suppose your question got downvoted due to this confusion. If you want the community to help with detailed answers the least you could do is to take the time to formulate your question with the same amount of care as you expect back.

Comment: Thanks! If I use Span then the size of the element will be based on the containing text, in this case &nbsp;. This means that only a small part of the image in the span will be shown. If I change from span to a div instead, then the image will be shown(element is the right size) but it will be placed on the row below the label(no float:left; used).

Answer (score 1):

Do you not want the image to the right of the label? You have specified `float: left;`. You may also want to change `.label` to `label` in line one of the css code.

Comment: this should allow you apply styling to the label element and not the label class; which - according to the shared markup - you don't have in your markup.

Comment: In my case I could remove .label and is would be the correct font size and color of the label. If I change the float: left to float: right then the div will be placed as far as possible to the right and thats not right. All I want is to place the div/span/imag or whatever works to the right of the label.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "CSS :after Selector"

Link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Answer (score 0):

Floats can be tricky... I would just make sure that the label is inline or inline-block, and that your image or image container also is inline or inline-block. They would then be aligned as text on a row. Yeay!